# Filter Array with properties and values of another array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays

```
const condition = [
  { iosSend: true },
  { androidSend: true }
]


const myArray = [
  {

    androidSend: false,
    iosSend: true,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    androidSend: true,
    iosSend: false,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    androidSend: true,
    iosSend: true,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    androidSend: false,
    iosSend: false,
    macosSend: true,
    id: 4
  }
]
```

Where I want to filter myArray with the following conditions:
Return a array with objects that has at least one of the keys of object inside condition array Equals false.

I mean, in the example, the return should return an array
with objects with ids 1, 2 and 4

Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of filtering if you wanted all items that match any condition.

```js
const condition = {
  iosSend: false,
  androidSend: false
};


const myArray = [
  {
    androidSend: false,
    iosSend: true,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    androidSend: true,
    iosSend: false,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    androidSend: true,
    iosSend: true,
    macosSend: false,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    androidSend: false,
    iosSend: false,
    macosSend: true,
    id: 4
  }
];

const conditions = Object.entries(condition);
const filteredArr = myArray.filter(o => {
  for (const [key, val] of conditions) {
    if (key in o && o[key] == val) return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

#EDIT:
I changed conditions to be either iosSend false or androidSend false after clarifying comment from author

Comment: Nice.. but in fact the answer is wrong.. it should print the object with id 1, 2 and 4... the answer is printing 1, 2 and 3

Comment: It's just reversed `if (key in o && o[key] !== val)` but making a condition object/array that you have think about to get the logic right doesn't make sense.

Comment: Updated question to check for either being false instead of true.